# What are some mechanisms to package cross-platform Electron apps in a single build?

Tags: node.js, cross-platform, node-modules, electron

I'm developing a desktop application based on Electron and I use [electron-packager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager) to create executables. The app uses some binary node modules such as `bcrypt`.

On my Mac, I package the app, targeting both OSX and Windows. The resulting package runs fine on OSX. But when I run the resulting Windows package (.exe and dependencies) on Windows 8.1 64 bits, the app throws an error (quite expectedly):

[image]

Is there any practice or tool that helps me be able to do the packaging once in any OS, even if the app depends on binary modules, and produce executables for Windows, OSX and Linux? For example, I'd like to run the build on OSX to produce executables for all three operating systems, instead of having to repeat the packaging for each platform

Answer (score 1):

You should look into removing native binary requirements from your project if possible. For example the module you mention, bcrypt, has another implementation which is full JS and doesn't require native binaries: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs

If you really need to include compiled binaries as a part of your dependencies you're probably going to have to design that part of the build/packaging automation yourself.